# LSP: Bad JSON object: ":", 97

Tags: lsp, json

I am using [gccemacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs), where emacs is build with `--with-native-compilation` configuration option.

After compilation is done,when I run `M-x lsp`: I start to have following error: `Bad JSON object: ":", 97`. This error occurs only for specific folder path, does not occur for my other github repos.

From logs:

```
json-read: Bad JSON object: ":", 97
File mode specification error: (json-object-format : 97)
Error running timer: (json-object-format ":" 97)

Error processing message (wrong-type-argument hash-table-p (:jsonrpc "2.0" :method "window/logMessage" :params (:type 4 :message "onHover 5:0 word=\"for\""))).
```

What may be the main reason of this error? Which `json` object is it referring? I get lost what might cause this error.

---

The way I install emacs:

```
dpkg -l | grep emacs | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo apt-get purge -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt install -y autoconf libgif-dev libtiff5-dev libgnutls28-dev libncurses5-dev \
     libgif-dev libharfbuzz-bin imagemagick libmagickwand-dev gcc \
     libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-bin imagemagick libmagickwand-dev libgccjit-10-dev \
     libgccjit0 gcc-10 libjansson4 libjansson-dev xaw3dg-dev texinfo libx11-dev
mkdir ~/git && cd ~/git
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
cd emacs && git checkout emacs-28
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-10 CXX=/usr/bin/gcc-10 && ./autogen.sh
./configure --with-native-compilation --with-json --with-modules --with-xpm\
            --with-harfbuzz --with-compress-install --with-threads \
            --with-included-regex --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-zlib \
            --with-jpeg --with-png --with-imagemagick --with-tiff --with-gnutls \
            --with-xft --with-xml2 --with-mailutils CPPFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline'
make -j$(nproc)
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ss
sudo rm -f /opt/ss/*
rm -f ~/.emacs.elc >/dev/null 2>&1 && rm -rf ~/var
sudo ln -s ~/git/emacs/lib-src/emacsclient /opt/ss/
sudo ln -s ~/git/emacs/src/emacs /opt/ss/
```

---

output for `lsp-doctor`:

```
Checking for Native JSON support: OK
Check emacs supports `read-process-output-max': OK
Check `read-process-output-max' default has been changed from 4k: OK
Byte compiled against Native JSON (recompile lsp-mode if failing when Native JSON available): OK
`gc-cons-threshold' increased?: OK
Using `plist' for deserialized objects? (refer to https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/#use-plists-for-deserialization): OK
Using emacs 28+ with native compilation?: OK

LSP :: lsp-mode 20220320.1029, Emacs 28.0.92, gnu/linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty stupid mistake on my end. This was not related to `LSP` or `emacs`, just wrong formated json file, effect `LSP-server` within all the files in the repo.

In a `package.json` file located in the github repo, I commented out one of line from `"author": ""` to `// "author": ""`, which was crashing `LSP` on my repo even if I only use it for `python`.

Cause of the error, which I remove them it is resolved:

```json
{
  // "author": "",
  // "homepage": ""
}
```

---

Helpful script to validate invalid `*.json` files, using [JSON Validator in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/876817/660555):

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
cd $BASE_DIR
for i in $(git ls-files '*.json'); do
    FILE=$i
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        jsonlint-php $FILE >/dev/null 2>&1
        status="$?"
        if [[ $status -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "E: $FILE is invalid json"
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
```